# Prawn Rails stroke_rectangle with line failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, line, praw

There is a continuity fault in the lines in the lower left corner of the drawn rectangle, as shown in the attached image.

code that draws the rectangle

```
pdf.rotate(45, origin: [140, 220]) do
  pdf.line_width 5
  pdf.stroke_color 'ff0000'
  pdf.stroke_rectangle [80, 325], 550, 100
  pdf.fill_color 'ff0000'
  pdf.draw_text 'CANCELADA', size: 70, at: [125, 245], style: :bold
end
```

Help please...

[rectangle failure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I8Yc.png)

[pdf full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ZbQ.png)

Comment: I've checked your snippet and it works ok.
See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8now16qyo5icgmh/test.pdf?dl=0
I'm using prawn (2.3.0) and ruby (2.6.3) in a macbook. Which versions are you using.

Comment: Hello Abinoam Jr., my versions were from gem prawn 2.1.0 and ruby 2.6.5.
I updated the version of the prawn gem to 2.3.0, but it still has the same problem.